# How do I know what Ruby gems are using another ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to know which ruby gems are using celluloid. How can I do so, without grepping the code of all the gems in my Gemfile?

Is there a simple command to list what gems are using another gem?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`gem dependency`](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-dependency) command with the `-R` (reverse) option. For example:

```
$ gem dependency -R rack
Gem rack-1.6.5
  bacon (>= 0, development)
  rake (>= 0, development)
  Used by
    rack-protection-1.5.3 (rack (>= 0))
    sinatra-1.4.7 (rack (~> 1.5))

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also look in the `Gemfile.lock` that will give you a really good snap shot.